# SHA1 returns different Digest

Tags: jsp, hash, sha1

```
    import java.security.MessageDigest;
    class Enc{

            public String encryptPassword(String password) throws Exception{
                    byte[] bArray=password.getBytes();
                    MessageDigest md=MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
                    md.reset();
                    md.update(bArray);
                    byte[] encoded=md.digest();
                    System.out.println(encoded.toString());

                    return "";
            }
            public static void main(String args[]){
                    try{
                    Enc e=new Enc();
                    e.encryptPassword("secret");
                    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
    }

/*

jabira-whosechild-lm.local 12:40:35 % while (true); do java Enc; done 
[B@77df38fd
[B@77df38fd
[B@60072ffb
[B@77df38fd
[B@6016a786
[B@60072ffb
[B@77df38fd
[B@77df38fd
[B@77df38fd
[B@77df38fd
[B@77df38fd
[B@77df38fd
[B@77df38fd
[B@6016a786
[B@6f507fb2
[B@77df38fd
[B@6016a786
[B@77df38fd
[B@77df38fd
[B@6016a786
*/
```

Answer (score 3):

You're just printing out `byte[].toString` which isn't the *contents* of the hash.

```
System.out.println(encoded.toString());
```

To display the hash as text, you should convert the byte array to hex or base64 - there are loads of snippets on Stack Overflow to accomplish that (e.g. using [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/)). If you don't need the hash as text, you can just leave it as a byte array though.

Also note that you shouldn't use this code:

```
byte[] bArray=password.getBytes()
```

That will use the system default character encoding, which can vary from system to system, and may not be able to encode all of Unicode. Use a fixed encoding such as UTF-8, which will always give the same results for the same input regardless of system defaults, and which can encode all of Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet I to MD5 an entire file. It worked for me when I MD5ed a file I wanted to sent to see if they client already had the same file. Complete source if needed can be found [here on Github](https://github.com/ChrisLundquist/Handbrake-Network-Queue/blob/master/java/src/FileTransfer.java)

```
private static String getMD5Digest(File file) {
    BufferedInputStream reader = null;
    String hexDigest = new String();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream(file));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    MessageDigest md = null;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    long fileLength = file.length();
    long bytesLeft = fileLength;
    int  read = 0;
    //Read our file into the md buffer
    while(bytesLeft > 0){
        try {
            read = reader.read(buffer,0, bytesLeft < buffer.length ? (int)bytesLeft : buffer.length);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        md.update(buffer,0,read);
        bytesLeft -= read;
    }
    byte[] digest = md.digest();
    for (int i = 0; i < digest.length;i++) {
        hexDigest += String.format("%02x" ,0xFF & digest[i]);
    }
    try {
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return hexDigest;
}
```

Comment: Why would you bother using the file length rather than just reading until the `read` call returned -1? Also, why create a new empty string instead of using ""? Also, if there's an IOException you're continuing as if nothing's happening... and if there's an unchecked exception, you're leaving the reader open... (You should use finally blocks.)

Comment: I never said it was good code. I said it was code that worked :)

Reading while bytesLeft > 0 is more deterministic. it might catch the edge case of /dev/zero, but I didn't try.

String.new and "" are equal in Ruby, I presume the same from Java.

These called are wrapped in a try catch on the server/client that clean up sockets if I recall correctly.

Yes it's not the best code.

Comment: Nope, "" and `new String()` aren't the same in Java - the latter always creates a new object, the former doesn't. (Usually it would be better to use a StringBuilder anyway.) Regardless of sockets, the *file* handle can be leaked in the above code due to the lack of a finally block - and the fact that it just stops on error instead of indicating to the caller that something's gone wrong is pretty nasty, IMO. (I would just let the method throw IOException.)

Comment: Good to know on "" vs new String()

Then half my functions had to have throws statements to throw it up the call stack even if they just threw what they caught.

Yes, the file handle could be leaked if in the use case of unplugging a USB stick while running. If it bothers you I will gladly accept a patch on the project :)

I think its like that because eclipse auto completed the block and I left it. Perhaps tools that help too much are dangerous.

Comment: You wouldn't bother catching the exception in the first place - just let it bubble up to the caller. Code ends up being much smaller if you *rarely* actually catch exceptions - which tends to be the right thing to do, as it's rare that you can really handle the error condition and continue successfully.